# Standards for PSP34 thumbnail/image and resource url?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, nft

Are there some standard attributes to use for URLs for images and other meta-information on PSP-34?
I see that RMRK has that but it is only on Kusama.

Answer (score 3):

[PSP34](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-34.md) is a standard at the contract level targeting `contracts-pallets`.

As mentioned in the standard:

> Attributes are more flexible than single tokenURI function like in `Erc721`. The list of required attributes for NFT should be defined in a separate proposal based on the scope of the usage.

There is no standard set for attributes for PSP34 yet, because it might be more restrictive rather than convenient.